# Woocommerce hide products in PRoduct-Category Listing

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For Standard Shop Listing we already use woocommerce_product_query to extend the SQL Query as follows:

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_hide_special_products');
function custom_hide_special_products($q) {
    global $current_oe;
    $current_meta_query = $q->get('meta_query');
    $current_meta_query[] = [
        'key' => '_ms_oes',
        'value' => $current_oe,
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ];
    $q->set('meta_query', $current_meta_query);
}
```

This works fine.

But: We als added product-category Links to our Main-Menu.
This links generate URLS like:

https://MYSHOPURL/product-category/categoryname

There my upper code will be called but it does not work. 
So do i have to use other action to change the product-query in the product-category Listing?